# How to add a download button to a music video website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Hello community i am trying to add a download button to this music website template i got online, i noticed the playlist in the music website template is written in java script, i have tried adding a download button but not working i have looked up tutorials and tried few codes i saw but no solution, i have also searched on stack overflow but no working solution, below is the code of the website well commented out , the playlist section started at line 491
thanks for your help in advance.

also an image of the website and the region where am trying to achieve the effect is here too, although any better plan will be appreciated, just want to add a download button that is all[music website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDnnE.jpg)

```
 <!--/music-right-->
                       <div class="music-right">
                            <!--/video-main-->
                             <div class="video-main">
                                <div class="video-record-list">
                                    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video jp-video-270p" role="application" aria-label="media player">
                                        <div class="jp-type-playlist">
                                            <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer" style="width: 480px; height: 270px;"><img id="jp_poster_0" src="video/play1.png" style="width: 480px; height: 270px; display: inline;"><video id="jp_video_0" preload="metadata" src="http://192.168.30.9/vijayaa/2015/Dec/mosaic/web/video/Ellie-Goulding.webm" title="1. Ellie-Goulding" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></video></div>
                                            <div class="jp-gui">
                                                <div class="jp-video-play" style="display: block;">
                                                    <button class="jp-video-play-icon" role="button" tabindex="0">play</button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="jp-interface">
                                                    <div class="jp-progress">
                                                        <div class="jp-seek-bar" style="width: 100%;">
                                                            <div class="jp-play-bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="jp-current-time" role="timer" aria-label="time">00:00</div>
                                                    <div class="jp-duration" role="timer" aria-label="duration">00:18</div>
                                                    <div class="jp-controls-holder">
                                                        <div class="jp-controls">
                                                            <button class="jp-previous" role="button" tabindex="0">previous</button>
                                                            <button class="jp-play" role="button" tabindex="0">play</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="jp-volume-controls">
                                                            <button class="jp-mute" role="button" tabindex="0">mute</button>
                                                            <button class="jp-volume-max" role="button" tabindex="0">max volume</button>
                                                            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                                                                <div class="jp-volume-bar-value" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="jp-toggles">

                                                            <button class="jp-full-screen" role="button" tabindex="0">full screen</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="jp-details" style="display: none;">
                                                        <div class="jp-title" aria-label="title">1. Ellie-Goulding</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="jp-playlist">
                                                <ul style="display: block;"><li class="jp-playlist-current"><div><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item-remove" style="display: none;">×</a><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item jp-playlist-current" tabindex="0">1. <span class="jp-artist">by Pixar</span></a></div></li><li><div><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item-remove" style="display: none;">×</a><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item" tabindex="0">2. Mark-Ronson-Uptown <span class="jp-artist">by Pixar</span></a></div></li><li><div><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item-remove" style="display: none;">×</a><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item" tabindex="0">3. Ellie-Goulding <span class="jp-artist">by Pixar</span></a></div></li><li><div><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item-remove" style="display: none;">×</a><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item" tabindex="0">4. Maroon-Sugar <span class="jp-artist">by Pixar</span></a></div></li><li><div><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item-remove" style="display: none;">×</a><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item" tabindex="0">5. Pharrell-Williams <span class="jp-artist">by Pixar</span></a></div></li><li><div><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item-remove" style="display: none;">×</a><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item" tabindex="0">6. Ellie-Goulding <span class="jp-artist">by Pixar</span></a></div></li><li><div><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item-remove" style="display: none;">×</a><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-playlist-item" tabindex="0">7. Pharrell-Williams <span class="jp-artist">by Pixar</span></a></div></li></ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="jp-no-solution" style="display: none;">
                                                <span>Update Required</span>
                                                To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- script for play-list -->
            <link href="css/jplayer.blue.monday.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function(){

                new jPlayerPlaylist({
                    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
                }, [

                    {
                        title:"1. Ellie-Goulding",
                        artist:"",
                        mp4: "video/Ellie-Goulding.mp4",
                        ogv: "video/Ellie-Goulding.ogv",
                        webmv: "video/Ellie-Goulding.webm",
                        poster:"video/play1.png"
                    },
                    {
                        title:"2. Mark-Ronson-Uptown",
                        artist:"",
                        mp4: "video/Mark-Ronson-Uptown.mp4",
                        ogv: "video/Mark-Ronson-Uptown.ogv",
                        webmv: "video/Mark-Ronson-Uptown.webm",
                        poster:"video/play2.png"
                    },
                    {
                        title:"3. Ellie-Goulding",
                        artist:"",
                        mp4: "video/Ellie-Goulding.mp4",
                        ogv: "video/Ellie-Goulding.ogv",
                        webmv: "video/Ellie-Goulding.webm",
                        poster:"video/play1.png"
                    },
                    {
                        title:"4. Maroon-Sugar",
                        artist:"",
                        mp4: "video/Maroon-Sugar.mp4",
                        ogv: "video/Maroon-Sugar.ogv",
                        webmv: "video/Maroon-Sugar.webm",
                        poster:"video/play4.png"
                    },
                    {
                        title:"5. Pharrell-Williams",
                        artist:"",
                        mp4: "video/Pharrell-Williams.mp4",
                        ogv: "video/Pharrell-Williams.ogv",
                        webmv: "video/Pharrell-Williams.webm",
                        poster:"video/play5.png"
                    },
                    {
                        title:"6. Ellie-Goulding",
                        artist:"",
                        mp4: "video/Ellie-Goulding.mp4",
                        ogv: "video/Ellie-Goulding.ogv",
                        webmv: "video/Ellie-Goulding.webm",
                        poster:"video/play1.png"
                    },
                    {
                        title:"7. Pharrell-Williams",
                        artist:"",
                        mp4: "video/Pharrell-Williams.mp4",
                        ogv: "video/Pharrell-Williams.ogv",
                        webmv: "video/Pharrell-Williams.webm",
                        poster:"video/play5.png"
                    }
                ], {
                    swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
                    supplied: "webmv,ogv,mp4",
                    useStateClassSkin: true,
                    autoBlur: false,
                    smoothPlayBar: true,
                    keyEnabled: true
                });

            });
            //]]>
                </script>
        <!-- //script for play-list -->

                            <!--//video-main-->
                            <!--/app_store-->
                                  <div class="apps">
                                            <h3 class="hd-tittle">Mosaic now available in</h3>
                                            <div class="banner-button">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/1.png" alt=""></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="banner-button green-button">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/2.png" alt=""></a>
                                            </div>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                              <!--//app_store-->
                             <!--/start-paricing-tables-->
                                <div class="price-section">
                                        <div class="pricing-inner">
                                            <h3 class="hd-tittle">Upgrade your Plan</h3>
                                            <div class="pricing">
                                                <div class="price-top">
                                                    <h3><span>$20</span></h3>
                                                    <h4>per year</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="price-bottom">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a class="icon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a><a class="text" href="#">Download unlimited songs</a><div class="clearfix"></div></li>
                                                        <li><a class="icon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a><a class="text" href="#">Stream songs in High Definition</a><div class="clearfix"></div></li>
                                                        <li><a class="icon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a><a class="text" href="#">No ads unlimited Devices</a><div class="clearfix"></div></li>
                                                        <li><a class="icon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a><a class="text" href="#">Stream songs in High Definition</a><div class="clearfix"></div></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <a href="single.html" class="price">Upgrade</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="pricing two">
                                                <div class="price-top">
                                                    <h3><span>$30</span></h3>
                                                    <h4>per year</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="price-bottom">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a class="icon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a><a class="text" href="#">Download unlimited songs</a><div class="clearfix"></div></li>
                                                        <li><a class="icon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a><a class="text" href="#">Stream songs in High Definition</a><div class="clearfix"></div></li>
                                                        <li><a class="icon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a><a class="text" href="#">No ads unlimited Devices</a><div class="clearfix"></div></li>
                                                        <li><a class="icon" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a><a class="text" href="#">Stream songs in High Definition</a><div class="clearfix"></div></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <a href="single.html" class="price">Upgrade</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--//end-pricing-tables-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                                 <!--//music-right-->
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <!-- /w3l-agile-its -->
                                    </div>
                    <!--body wrapper start-->

                    <div class="review-slider">
                            <div class="tittle-head">
                                <h3 class="tittle">Featured Albums <span class="new"> New</span></h3>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            </div>
                             <ul id="flexiselDemo1">
                            <li>
                                <a href="single.html"><img src="images/v1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="slide-title"><h4>Adele21 </div>
                                <div class="date-city">
                                    <h5>Jan-02-16</h5>
                                    <div class="buy-tickets">
                                        <a href="single.html">READ MORE</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="single.html"><img src="images/v2.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="slide-title"><h4>Adele21</h4></div>
                                <div class="date-city">
                                    <h5>Jan-02-16</h5>
                                    <div class="buy-tickets">
                                        <a href="single.html">READ MORE</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="single.html"><img src="images/v3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="slide-title"><h4>Shomlock</h4></div>
                                <div class="date-city">
                                    <h5>Jan-02-16</h5>
                                    <div class="buy-tickets">
                                        <a href="single.html">READ MORE</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="single.html"><img src="images/v4.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="slide-title"><h4>Stuck on a feeling</h4></div>
                                <div class="date-city">
                                    <h5>Jan-02-16</h5>
                                    <div class="buy-tickets">
                                        <a href="single.html">READ MORE</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="single.html"><img src="images/v5.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="slide-title"><h4>Ricky Martine </h4></div>
                                <div class="date-city">
                                    <h5>Jan-02-16</h5>
                                    <div class="buy-tickets">
                                        <a href="single.html">READ MORE</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="single.html"><img src="images/v6.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="slide-title"><h4>Ellie Goluding </h4></div>
                                <div class="date-city">
                                    <h5>Jan-02-16</h5>
                                    <div class="buy-tickets">
                                        <a href="single.html">READ MORE</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="single.html"><img src="images/v6.jpeg" alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="slide-title"><h4>Fifty Shades </h4></div>
                                <div class="date-city">
                                    <h5>Jan-02-16</h5>
                                    <div class="buy-tickets">
                                        <a href="single.html">READ MORE</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(window).load(function() {

                      $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel({
                            visibleItems: 5,
                            animationSpeed: 1000,
                            autoPlay: true,
                            autoPlaySpeed: 3000,            
                            pauseOnHover: false,
                            enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                            responsiveBreakpoints: { 
                                portrait: { 
                                    changePoint:480,
                                    visibleItems: 2
                                }, 
                                landscape: { 
                                    changePoint:640,
                                    visibleItems: 3
                                },
                                tablet: { 
                                    changePoint:800,
                                    visibleItems: 4
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>    
                    </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <!--body wrapper end-->
 <!-- /w3l-agile -->
                </div>
          <!--body wrapper end-->
             <div class="footer">
            <div class="footer-grid">
                <h3>Navigation</h3>
                <ul class="list1">
                  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="radio.html">All Songs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="browse.html">Albums</a></li>
                  <li><a href="radio.html">New Collections</a></li>
                  <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-grid">
                <h3>Our Account</h3>
                <ul class="list1">
                  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5">Your Account</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Personal information</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Addresses</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Discount</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Orders history</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Addresses</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Search Terms</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-grid">
                <h3>Our Support</h3>
                <ul class="list1">
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Site Map</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Search Terms</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Advanced Search</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Addresses</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
                  <div class="footer-grid">
                    <h3>Newsletter</h3>
                    <p class="footer_desc">Nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
                    <div class="search_footer">
                     <form>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Email...." required="">
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                      </form>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="footer-grid footer-grid_last">
                    <h3>About Us</h3>
                    <p class="footer_desc">Diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat enim ad minim veniam,.</p>
                    <p class="f_text">Phone:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;00-250-2131</p>
                    <p class="email">Email : &nbsp;<span><a href="mailto:mail@example.com">info(at)mailing.com</a></span></p>   
                 </div>
                 <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the download button this way

```html
<a href="http://192.168.30.9/vijayaa/2015/Dec/mosaic/web/video/Ellie-Goulding.webm"><button> download</button></a>
```